# Cannot find variable in a xarray dataset even though the variable exists

Tags: python, python-xarray

When I try to extract a variable from a xarray dataset (e.g, 'prateavesfc'), the Keyerror shows even when it does exist.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao5iF.png)/vkHws.png

Comment: Please specify if your ds is a dict type object or DataFrame or Series ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a pydap bug. Please refer to this github [issue](https://github.com/pydap/pydap/issues/121#issuecomment-650707053). You will likely have to reinstall the library according to the comment.

Comment: Yeah that was a bug due to xarray dependencies. I switch to a Linux system and it works.